# How to Programatically read the Documentation section of a WSDL in C#

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wsdl

i am using a WSDL file to create a the proxy class file, this service has a big Enumeration. the description for each enum value is in documentation section, how can i programatically read that section?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A WSDL file is always an XML file, so you can open it and read the elements data. For example, given the [eBay Services WSDL file](http://developer.ebay.com/webservices/latest/eBaySvc.wsdl), you can query the documentation of the value `COD` of the enumeration `BuyerPaymentMethodCodeType` like this:

```
    XmlDocument wsdlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    wsdlDoc.Load(@"D:\temp\eBaySvc.wsdl");

    XmlNamespaceManager nsMgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(wsdlDoc.NameTable);
    nsMgr.AddNamespace("xs", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");

    XmlNode node = wsdlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//xs:simpleType[@name='BuyerPaymentMethodCodeType']/xs:restriction/xs:enumeration[@value='COD']/xs:annotation/xs:documentation", nsMgr);
    string description = node.InnerText;
```